# How to derive this conditional probability?

Tags: probability

I have two random variables $Y$ and $X$ which are not independent of each other. I would like to compute $E(Y|E(Y|X))$

Since $E(Y|X)$ is a function of $X$, I would think $E(Y|E(Y|X))=E(Y|X)$. Is there a simple way to prove this or disprove this?

thanks,

Comment: @Eric The statement also holds for independent random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is indeed true. It is a consequence of the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), which states that whenever we have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with two sub $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$, such that $\mathcal{G}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{G}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{F}$,
then we have
$$\mathbb{E}[Y\:| \: \mathcal{G}_1] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y\: | \: \mathcal{G}_2]\: | \: \mathcal{G}_1]$$
for any integrable random variable $Y$. In particular if we set $\mathcal{G}_1= \sigma(\mathbb{E}[Y \: | \: X])$ and $\mathcal{G}_2 = \sigma(X)$, then the law of iterated expectations allows us to compute
$$\mathbb{E}[Y \: | \: \mathbb{E}[Y \: | \: X]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y \: | \: X] \: | \: \mathbb{E}[Y \: | \: X]] = \mathbb{E}[Y \: | \: X].$$